# Powershell regular expression match return empty string

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I am using regular expression to find strings in Powershell, and match function returns empty string lines as well as matched lines.

For the following four lines of text file input.txt,

```
[abc]

abc

[123]

123
```

The code below prints out `abc/blank line/123/blank line`. I expected it only prints out `abc` and `123`, wonder how this happened.

```
$readArray = Get-Content(input.txt)
foreach($line in $readArray) {
   $re = [regex] *** // Find the string in bracket

   $key = $re.match($line)
   if($key -ne $null) {
      write-host -$key.group[1].value
   }
}
```

Comment: `$re = [regex] ***` looks like some kind of mistake. Can you post the actual regex you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (use select-string) -

```
Get-Content -FilePath input.txt | 
  Select-String '\[(.+?)\]') | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to get the content within tags:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fY3wD4/1)**

[image]